# Beginner question about external java libraries

Tags: java

This command compiles:

```
javac -classpath google-collections.jar Test.java
```

What's the command to run Test.class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -classpath google-collections.jar:. Test`

The ":." adds the current directory to the classpath so java can find Test.class

Comment: Is `Test.class` in the current directory?  Does it have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Comment: does Test.java contain a main method?

Comment: Yup, and yup. Although I've found that putting the classpath arguments in front of Test makes java.exe unable to find Test at all.

My code: http://pastebin.com/m36e6bbba

Comment: Mea culpa.  Forgot to add the current directory to the classpath.  Edited.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the problem. Fixed.

Comment: Embarrassing mistake on my part... I should know better after all these years! :/  Sorry for the false start.

Answer (score 3):

The following will have the current directory and the `google-colletions.jar` as the classpath:

```
java -cp .;google-collections.jar Test
```

This will run the `main` method in the `Test` class with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[])
```

**Note:**

As noted by Paul Tomblin in the comments, the separator character for the classpath is different depending on the platform on which `javac` is run on.

For Solaris/Linux (and apparently Mac OS), the separator character is a colon (`:`), while on Windows, it is a semi-colon (`;`).

Reference:

- [Setting the classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) (Solaris)
- [Setting the classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) (Windows)

Comment: The separator on the -cp (or -classpath if you prefer) can only be ';' on Windows.  On Linux and Mac OS it must be ':', and I believe ':' works on Windows as well.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin, Thanks for pointing that out. As it turns out, it seems like only ';' can be used as a separator on Windows `javac`.

Comment: @coobird Oh neat, that's good to know.  Haven't done Java on Windows for so long... :)

Comment: It appears that the difference in separator characters used by the shell in each platform.

Comment: @Zoogie, If : is used as a delimiter, then `javac -cp d:collections.jar Test` would be problamatic.  Here `d:collections.jar` refers to the far in the current directory under `d` drive